# Does sqlplus uses TNS_ADMIN variable?

Tags: oracle, unix

Please tell me does sqlplus uses TNS_ADMIN variable on UNIX and AIX? Can we able to locate sqlplus if this variable could not be located?

Comment: Duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1818016/what-is-the-use-of-tnsadmin-variable-in-oracle

Comment: @OMG Ponies, that was also my question, I have raised it again

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sqlplus is just an executable file after all. Unix searches the directories listed in `$PATH` for it. You can use `which sqlplus` to find out full path to sqlplus.
Sqlplus itself can use `$TNS_ADMIN`, but absense of this variable cannot prevent OS from locating sqlplus.

Comment: Exactly, I am amazed why my sqlplus caould not be located if TNS_ADMIN is not there

Answer (score 0):

On Linux the answer is "Yes":

```
export TNS_ADMIN=$ORACLE HOME/network/admin
```

Comment: What would happen if this variable is not found?

Comment: This variable points to TNSNAMES.ora, configuration file that defines databases addresses for establishing connections to them.

Comment: If tnsnames.ora could not be located , then the login string could not be built. Are there any chances that sqlplus could not be located?